# Python Variables not working

Tags: python

While making a program that solves a Rubik's cube on python I wrote this bit of code for turning the front face of a Rubik's cube:

```
c_top = top
c_front = front
c_left = left
c_right = right
c_back = back
c_bottom = bottom
for x in range(6,9):
    right[x] = c_bottom[x]
    top[x] = c_right[x]
    left[x] = c_top[x]
    bottom[x] = c_left[x]
```

For some reason it did something odd and changed c_bottom and other c_ things even though I only ran the function the code was in once. Does anyone know why?

Comment: No, not from that code. What are top, front etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `c_bottom` and `bottom` are both variables referencing the same object. That means `c_bottom[x]` is the same as `bottom[x]` for every `x` in `range(0, len(bottom))`.

So when you do `bottom[x] = c_left[x]`, `c_bottom[x]` also gets modified.

A simplified example:

```
a = ['Hello', 0, 0]
b = a

print(a[0]) # <<< Hello
b[0] = 'Goodbye'
print(a[0]) # <<< Goodbye
```

Edit: To solve this, you can either:

a) make `c_side` be a copy of side. If they're list, for example, you can do

```
c_bottom = list(bottom)
```

b) However, if you only want those `c_side` variables to perform that cycle, you can avoid doing copies with:

```
for x in range(6,9):
    right[x], top[x], left[x], bottom[x] = bottom[x], right[x], top[x], left[x]
```

Comment: How do I not have c_bottom be modified?

Comment: I have just edited my answer to answer that